# ENOBUFS when using http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've set up a node web server which queries several webservices at every incoming request (via http.get). When the request return the web server will return the aggregated content to the user (coordinated by `async`).

Currently I'm doing about 10concurrenting requests to 8 different webservices that are as well located on the same machine.
(it's a test setup)

Everything works fine when triggering the setup from the browser, but when I'm using `ab` to put a little load on the system (`ab -n 1500 -c 42 127.0.0.1:31330/`) after a short while I keep getting `ENOBUFS` errors.

I found very little on the internet regarding this issue.
Does it have to do with the fact that the connection pool of my operating system simply overloads and thus is not able to perform any more requests as well as accept any new connections?
Or is it simply a windows issue that will not appear on any other unix like system? (I'm using Win 7 x64)
If it has to do with connections, does this issue exist on any operating system whatever technology (node.js, python, php etc.) is used?

**Update:**
It appears that indeed some kind of connection pool is filling up, when I got that error from node at the same time accessing any other webpage is not possible anymore.

Is there anything that can be done here?

Comment: From `man errno`: `ENOBUFS         No buffer space available (POSIX.1 (XSI STREAMS option))`

Comment: yes but I'm running the script on windows 7 x64

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you learn any more about avoiding this problem?

Comment: Hi, i found this page: http://itamarst.org/writings/win32sockets.html According to it the enobufs problem occurs because of the limited buffer size in windows. (see the very last paragraph) I'm not totally sure if switching to linux will solve the problem, but I did not experience this problem on a linux machine. as i'm not really sure i did not post this as a answer because i did not want do mislead anyone. also the thing with not being able to open any internetpage anymore looks consistent to the buffer issue on windows.

Comment: @zaphod1984 do you still experience this with nodejs 0.10 ?

Comment: I've not tested it recently but it looks like it is not a node issue but relates to the fact that I'm on windows. the problem did not occur when i tested on linux.

Comment: Any insights? I've got the same error.