# Very simple Node.js client throws error ENOBUFS after many http requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following set up:

A node.js client makes end-to-end requests to a node.js server. After less than a minute, the client fails with error ENOBUFS.

**client:**

```
(function(){ 

        var loadUrl=function(){
            var http=require('http');   
            var querystring=require('querystring'); 
            var options = {host:"localhost",port:1337,path:'/post',method:'POST'};

            var req = http.request(options, function(res){              
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                var body='';
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    body+=chunk;
                });           
                res.on('end', function (chunk) {
                    loadUrl();   
                });   
            }); 
            req.on('error', function(e) {
              console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
            });
            var post_data = querystring.stringify({id:0});
            req.write(post_data);
            req.end();
        }
        setTimeout(loadUrl,1000);   
    })()
```

**server:**

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513415/enobufs-when-using-http-get) is similar, I am posting this as a generalization of the original question (I am using post rather than get), with a test case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue appears to be a problem with the Node.js HTTP client connection pool.

If you add the option `agent:false` to the `options` argument of the [`http.request()` function](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) it will disable connection pooling and have each request use the header `Connection: close`.  This change seems to allow the client code to run indefinitely.

```javascript
var options = {agent:false, host:"localhost", port:1337, /*...*/ };
```

Doing this will degrade the performance of the HTTP clients and you should see frequent pauses in the client process (presumably while the V8 runtime does garbage collection).  But it does seem to solve your problem!

Per @joshp's comment, see if this issue has been addressed in a later version of Node.js or consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Nice answer. So for @Tom it's probably worth looking at issues for Node to see if it's known or addressed in a later version.

Comment: @maerics - Thank you! on what os did you reproduce this? Did anyone else reproduce the problem? On which operating system(s)? Wondering if this is Windows specific.

Comment: @Tom: I reproduced on Mac OS X 10.7 using node v0.6.10.