# ENOBUFS error running tests through Karma

Tags: node.js, karma-runner, node-http-proxy

I am using Karma to test my node server.  After about a minute of running there is a "failed to proxy" error with error code 'ENOBUFS'.  The error happens in 'karma/lib/middleware/proxy.js'.  I have read a similar issue here:
[Very simple Node.js client throws error ENOBUFS after many http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603860/very-simple-node-js-client-throws-error-enobufs-after-many-http-requests/10604622#10604622)

and some more background here:
https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3269

But I cannot find a workaround for my situation since the http requests are out of my control.  Is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: What platform is this? Have you established whether or not you're running out of ports? (Is this just a cosmetic issue? You don't actually need to support so many connections from the same source IP address, right? Or is this some application where all the connections are between the same two endpoints?)

Comment: This happens on Windows 7, Windows 8 and Ubuntu.  When I run 'netstat -nt' I see hundreds of sockets in 'TIME_WAIT' status.

Comment: Is there an actual problem or is this just a cosmetic issue?

Comment: There is an actual problem.  The tests fail because the server becomes unresponsive.

Comment: When the server is unresponsive, it is out of ephemeral ports? (Look at the `netstat` output.)